# mysql get opposite results of full join

Tags: mysql, join

This query gives me the results I want and it works perfectly.

```
        SELECT * 
        FROM npc5 
        FULL JOIN joeall ON merchnumber = joeall.id 
        WHERE date='$period' 
        ORDER BY DATE");
```

Now I would like to get the the records where the merchant number is not in the `joeall` table, something like `ON merchnumber != joeall.id`

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` extension: it's being deprecated, switch to `PDO` or `mysqli_*`

Comment: Also, you don't want to use `SELECT *` unless you have a good, specific reason ("can't be bothered" isn't one!) for doing so. It is easier to maintain your code that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a multi-field index on `date` and `merchnumber` to keep your speed up.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM npc5 
    WHERE date='$period' 
    AND merchnumber NOT IN (SELECT id FROM JOEALL)
    ORDER BY DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

Excluding any id that is found in the NOT IN's SELECT STATEMENT

```
$query1 = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM npc5 
    WHERE date='$period' 
    AND merchnumber NOT IN (SELECT id FROM joeall)
    ORDER BY DATE");
```

Answer (score 1):

correlated sub queries can be very inefficient and should be avoided every time possible.

Therefore I wouldn't recommend you to do

```
SELECT * 
FROM npc5 
WHERE date='$period' 
AND merchnumber NOT IN (SELECT id FROM JOEALL)
ORDER BY DATE
```

Have a look on http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=42&ID=75

I recommend you to change it for something like

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM npc5 LEFT JOIN JOEALL on 
    npc5.merchnumber = joeall.id 
WHERE 
    joeall.id is null 
        and 
    date='$period'
ORDER BY
    date;
```

Regards